# Check acces database for highest value in load

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I got a small program for a big archive, people are given family numbers to keep them together.
The problem is before this was in a big word file and now i created this program and created a access database for this.
The one thing that i do not know, is how many errors there are.
I am certain there are plenty of them.

The idea is to show the highest family number used in a textbox.
This textbox has to filled in the load.
Though i got no idea how i would go about coding that part, seen some examples but non of those were used in the load.
And the attempts i made with that even though rather old did not work for me.

And i am not sure if opening a connection to the DB in the load is going to cause problems later on when i searching through the database, since i have to open a connection for this also.

So i am hoping someone might be able to give me some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: please add some code or some examples of your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Create a query of the load:
select Max(familynumber) from load
as the data source of the text box